# Scrape specific field

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The following code works fine in scraping fields from a webpage, however I want to scrape one more piece of information (actual study completion date) that is on the webpage.

I have added it at the end of the list named "subset", thinking it would find this field and scrape the info as it has with the others. But it is not scraping this field?

How can I get this ?

(for easy reference the URL is https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/study/NCT02170532

```
import bs4
from collections import defaultdict
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def clinicalTrialsGov(nctid):
    data = defaultdict(list)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/" + nctid + "?displayxml=true").text, "xml")
    subset = ['intervention_type', 'study_type', 'allocation', 'intervention_model', 'primary_purpose', 'masking', 'enrollment', 'official_title', 'condition', 'minimum_age', 'maximum_age', 'gender', 'healthy_volunteers', 'phase', 'primary_outcome', 'secondary_outcome', 'number_of_arms','actual_study_completion_date']

    for tag in soup.find_all(subset):
        data['ct{}'.format(tag.name.capitalize())].append(tag.get_text(strip=True))

    for key in data:
        print('{}: {}'.format(key, ', '.join(data[key])))

clinicalTrialsGov('NCT02170532')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you want to add it. It seems to have to come from that other url.
You can select for the `td` which `has` a child with `data-term` attribute with value "Study Completion Date", then use an adjacent sibling combinator (`+`) to move to the associated date `td`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

def clinicalTrialsGov(nctid):
    with requests.Session() as s:
        data = defaultdict(list)
        soup = bs(s.get("https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/" + nctid + "?displayxml=true").text, "xml")
        subset = ['intervention_type', 'study_type', 'allocation', 'intervention_model', 'primary_purpose', 'masking', 'enrollment', 'official_title', 'condition', 'minimum_age', 'maximum_age', 'gender', 'healthy_volunteers', 'phase', 'primary_outcome', 'secondary_outcome', 'number_of_arms','primary_completion_date']

        for tag in soup.find_all(subset):
            data['ct{}'.format(tag.name.capitalize())].append(tag.get_text(strip=True))

        for key in data:
            print('{}: {}'.format(key, ', '.join(data[key])))

        soup = bs(s.get(f'https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/study/{nctid}').text, 'lxml')
        data['actual_study_completion_date'] = soup.select_one('td:has([data-term="Study Completion Date"]) + td').text
        data['Study Start Date'] = soup.select_one('td:has([data-term="Study Start Date"]) + td').text
        data['Actual Primary Completion Date'] = soup.select_one('td:has([data-term="Primary Completion Date"]) + td').text
    return data
    
clinicalTrialsGov('NCT02170532')
```

Comment: Wow, youre a wizard, I have also seen you comment on prior posts regarding ClinicalTrials so im glad to see you :D

Would this same method apply to "Study Start Date" and "Actual Primary Completion Date", if so can you please include this into your comment, it would complete this scrape.

Comment: yes, I have seen the actual study completion date and primary completion date have different values after looking at multiple trials. So i was hoping to have them as their own separate fields

Comment: I have added those in now.

Comment: An absolute legend of clinical trials. Thank you so much, and am so thankful you still help out the community given the last time you commented was over a year ago to a similar post :)

Comment: hi, i think there was a repeat with the first data field -Actual Study Completion Date (after data-term) and the third data field Actual priamry completion date (after date-term) are they pulling the same fields? Both has data-term= Primary completion date.   In NCT = NCT04796220 for example, the fields are different, but the code will pull a repeating value. I tried to change on my end, but cannot seem to get it

Comment: oof let me have a look!

Comment: Fixed. Silly me. Overwrote the wrong one in testing. Sorry.

Comment: Ah. i just got it too- when I did my version i used lowercase for some reason :D. Thank you so much boss!